# airys equation convergance interval or divergence

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Airy’s equation
    which is given by

$$ y''-x*y=0$$
two solutions are

> $$ y_1(x)=1+ \sum^{\infty}_{m=1} \frac{x^{3m}}{(2*3)(5*6)\dots *((3m-1)*3m)}$$

and

> $$ y_2(x)=x+\sum^{\infty}_{m-1} \frac{x^{3m+1}}{(3*4)(6*7) \dots ((3m)*(3m+1))}$$

find if the series convergence divergence. what interval???

_______________________________________________________________-

back story ritting a loop program *I think* from the programming. just making sure thinigs line up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The convergence radius for $y_1$ and $y_2$ is $\infty$. You may use [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test) and with $y_1$ for instance write
$$\lim_\infty\dfrac{a_{m+1}}{a_m}=\lim_\infty\dfrac{\frac{x^{3m+3}}{(2\times3)(5\times6)\dots \times((3m-1)\times3m) \times((3m+2)\times(3m+3))}}{\frac{x^{3m}}{(2\times3)(5\times6)\dots \times((3m-1)\times3m)}} = \lim_\infty\dfrac{x^3}{(3m+2)(3m+3)}=0$$
then $y_1$ is converge on $\mathbb{R}$. [Fuchs's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuchs%27_theorem) is applicable for Airy’s equation as well.